# Show each function's calling convention using objdump or similar

Tags: c, calling-convention, objdump

I have an executable file (or a `.o`) generated by GCC from C source files. **How can I show the calling convention for each function contained within the file, using `objdump` or a similar tool?**

### Reason

When looking at the disassembly, I seem to have a function `A()` which calls another function `B(x, y)` by pushing `y` and `x` on the stack, but `B(x, y)` looks for its parameters in registers.

I don't see any `__cdecl`, `__stdcall` or similar annotation on the C source code of `B(x, y)`, and there don't see any C/C++ incompatibility weirdness, so I'd like to query the convention it's using from the actual `.o` or executable file instead of guessing at random.

Comment: Disassemble and see how the function calls work?

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, that's what I've done, but reading 100's of lines of assembly is difficult, and it only tells me what the function seems to do, but not the name of the calling convention, so I have to guess-reverse-engineer that.

Comment: Most likely you'll find the calling convention from operating system/hardware documentation faster than reverse-engineering objdump output. A web search for "<your platform> calling convention" might be quite revealing (I somehow sense this might even be linux of a sort).

Comment: @SamiLaine I don't see how this can help me... In a C program, functions do not necessarily all use the same calling convention, and I see that the caller uses a different one than the callee, which of course doesn't work. I didn't put any annotations to change the default calling convention (but it's not my code). The result still is that I have two different calling conventions within the same C file. I'd like to know the hard facts and know what is the effective calling convention of the calle, so I can then look for *what* is causing that behaviour (maybe some attribute somewhere).

Comment: I don't think you can query the object file. However, on the x86 32b platform at least, there is a standard convention for c fct call, syscall, and assembly called from c by which you know how to hand on parameters. If your function B() really deviates from it (if what you say happens, does, it would), this is very bad coding, and nothing short of disassembling the fct to check will help you. You could post asm code snippets of you like so others can check if maybe you misread the assembly.

Comment: @gnometorule, @SamiLaine : A colleague found the problem: somewhere in the (rather long) file there was a `#pragma` which changed the GCC optimization level (from `O2` to `O0` I think). So, `B` was defined with `O2` active, and `A` was defined with `O0` active. This shouldn't be a problem, but it seems that GCC version chokes on it, and within `A` it calls `B` as if `B` was `O0` too, but `O0` and `O2` have different calling conventions. I think that information is contained in the `.o`, because when calling a function in a separate `.o`, GCC knows the convention and generates the right code.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: Ah. As to "this shouldn't be a problem": this can easily be (as you noticed, obviously). To give you anopther example: -O2 enables -fcaller-saves (==usually callee saved registers are saved by caller). If a caller and callee don't agree on this, you can easily corrupt registers. So best to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A colleague found the problem: somewhere in the (rather long) file
>   there was a `#pragma` which changed the GCC optimization level (from `O2`
>   to `O0` I think). So, `B` was defined with `O2` active, and `A` was defined
>   with `O0` active. This shouldn't be a problem, but it seems that GCC
>   version chokes on it, and within `A` it calls `B` as if `B` was `O0` too, but
>   `O0` and `O2` have different calling conventions.

… interesting, good observation.

> I think that information is contained in the `.o`, because when calling
>   a function in a separate `.o`, GCC knows the convention and generates
>   the right code.

This reasoning is wrong. In your case, `B` must have been defined as `static`; the optimization of loading parameters from registers is not done in functions with external linkage. And this explains why *when calling a function in a separate `.o`, GCC … generates the right code* - it just doesn't perform that optimization then; thus it isn't necessary that *GCC knows the convention* from some *information … contained in the `.o`* - which isn't there.